# Exception remaining on stack after it was caught

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

It seems I have stumbled into a situation where an exception is still available as after catch block. It is 100% reproducable in the situation I encounter it in, but I cannot make a test that exactly reproduces this scenario.

See this image for a debugging situation:
[image]

Situation is as follows:

1. ASync task is executed an awaited.
2. Task is in set to a faulted state and throws an exception.
3. Code steps through the catch block, **handling the exception**. <- As expected
4. Exception is not cleared from stack after catch block has finished. <- Not as expected

Final result: Marshall.GetExceptionCode() != 0 in all code that follows after the catch block.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening here?

Comment: If you're in debug mode exceptions do still show up..

Comment: All you're describing is internal undefined behaviour, and there's no contractual guarantees defined by the spec. Do you actually have a specific problem you need to solve?

Comment: It is a side-effect of the way the C# compiler *rewrites* a method that uses async/await.  The debugger's context is that rewritten method, not your original one.  Get more insight about this rewriting logic by looking at the generated code with ildasm.exe

Comment: @Luaan this is used to determine if anything happened in a using block. See for example: https://ayende.com/blog/2577/did-you-know-find-out-if-an-exception-was-thrown-from-a-finally-block

Comment: Well, that's what you get for relying on undefined behaviour. The runtime has no contract whatsoever that says "the `Dispose` method will have `Marshal.GetExceptionCode` return a non-zero value if an exception has been thrown before the `finally` block executed". Newsflash: hacks may result in unexpected behaviour. Exception handlers and `finally` clauses are handled in a very different manner, see the ECMA-spec for CLR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack doesn't belong to you, it belongs to the runtime. Your .NET code shouldn't depend on the precise way the stack is handled.

`Marshal.GetExceptionCode` is used exclusively for interop and compiler support, and shouldn't really be used in .NET user code anyway, since you have no idea what happened between two (seemingly innocuous) lines of .NET code.

Stick to the specs, and stop relying on undefined behaviour. It's not like there's a huge amount of undefined behaviour in .NET.